# how to call a function automatically with the use of timer?

Tags: java

I have written a code to send email to users which is working properly.
But with this I want to add a timer which automatically sends the email to the user by setting it at a particular time interval.

So need help to get to know how can this be done..

Comment: Have you googled around and looked at for example quartz timers with crontab expressions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a construct similar to this one:

```
public class TestClass {
    public long myLong = 1234;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TestClass test = new TestClass();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                test.doStuff();
            }
        }, 0, test.myLong);
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do that is using `ScheduledExecutorService`, which is recommended by Joshua Bloch in "Effective Java":

```
final int initialDelay = 0; // the initial delay in minutes (or whatever you specify below)
final int period = 5; // the period in minutes (...)
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendEmail();
    }
}, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
// or, with Java 8:
ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> sendEmail(), initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
// when finished:
ex.shutdown();
```

See javadoc for `ScheduledExecutorService`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html